# Spring MVC. Rendering layout

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'am new to Java Spring MVC. Official documentation is very poor and i've got a lot of questions about rendering pages in Spring.

I have page and top block with menu. This menu must be dynamic and must be displayed on all pages.  In PHP frameworks this is very common and very easy task. But Spring makes my brain explode.. How can i separate rendering of this menu in some peace of logic and tell spring to render it all the time? For example in JSP. Shoud I use beans or other stuff?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This isn't mentioned in Spring because Spring MVC isn't a layout engine, it just delegates to other frameworks that are.

Answer (score 3):

> Official documentation is very poor

No it isn't. Its the [one place](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) I always refer back to.

I use a [jsp include](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/12/syntaxref1214.html) and yes pass a java bean to the jsp from the controller. The included jsp will be cached the first time it is included.  In other places I connect to a controller using jquery and [ajax](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/), which dynamically updates the page.

I'd suggest the [official tutorials](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Interface21TeamBlog%20%28SpringSource%20Team%20Blog%29), and [krams](http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html) as good starting points.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find much information about this in the Spring documentation because it's out of the scope of Spring.

You can use JSP includes just as you would do PHP includes. This will however force you to repeat the page layout and the include in each and every page of the application :

```
<jsp:include page="/menu.jspf" />
```

Or use a templating engine, like Sitemesh or Apache Tiles (see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles for Tiles integration in Spring).

Comment: But if I need some data to be available in menu.jsp where should I get it? From consoller& From bean?

Comment: From the model. Spring has a notion of Model, which is a glorified Map. You store whatever you want in this model, and since the JSP EL and the JSTL is designed to access Java beans, the model should contain instances of beans.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use <jsp:include page="/menu.jsp" /> where "/menu.jsp" is a path to your menu jsp.

There are other solutions like using [tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/), but <jsp:include> should do.

Comment: But if I need some data to be available in menu.jsp where should I get  it? From consoller& From bean?

Comment: @zim32 You can get it the same way you'd get it if the menu was on the same jsp.

Comment: @zim32 Meaning that you probably have to put it in ModelAndView returned by your controller or whatever else you're using to pass the data to views.

Comment: This is not a good idea to get this data from controller. Because I shoul run this code manually on every controller. This is not good )

Comment: @zim32 no it doesn't work like that. The included jsp will be cached.